# Action of the group ring $\mathbb{Z}[\text{Gal}(K/\mathbb{Q})]$ on the field $K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be an algebraic number field, let $G$=Gal($K/\mathbb{Q}$). Let $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ be the group ring, or the set of formal sums

$$\left\lbrace\sum a_i\sigma_i : a_i\in \mathbb{Z}, \sigma_i \in G\right\rbrace$$

We can make this into a group by setting $\sum a_i\sigma_i+\sum b_i\sigma_i=\sum(a_i+b_i)\sigma_i$.

It seems that the identity in this group is $0\in \mathbb{Z}$, which is fine unless we define the action of $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ on $K$.

The natural action is

$$ k^{\sum a_i\sigma_i}=  \prod (\sigma_i(k))^{a_i}$$

but this doesn't hold the property that $k^0=k$. I realise that I can use the group identity, $\sigma_1$ to have this property (where $\sigma_1$ is the trivial automorphism), but $\sigma_1$ is not the identiy in ($\mathbb{Z}[G], +)$.

Is there something that I am missing here, is it different when we consider group actions like this?

Comment: You shouldn't think of the group ring just as an additive group; the clue is in the name. In fact, a $G$-module is the same thing as a module over the ring $\mathbb Z[G]$.

Comment: @Engloutie So how does this help when I think of the action on the field? Do I need to take a 'ring action'?

Comment: Otherwise known as a module structure, yes.

Comment: the action as you have described it is on the multiplicative group of the field, not on the field itself

Comment: @Engloutie Would you consider writing what you mean in an answer? I know some module theory, but little homological algebra.

Comment: @DavidHolden Do you mean that I have described a $\mathbb{Z}[G]$-module, $M$,  where we take $M$ to be $K^{\times}$?

Comment: Yes, if you want $K$ itself, you'll need to take $\sum a_i\sigma_i(k)$. Also, I'm not sure what else to write in an answer.

Comment: Ok thanks, I think I've got it now. So  in the map I have described we have $k^{\sigma_1}=k$, and since $\sigma_1=1_R$, this holds with the axioms for a module.